# Django Time issues

Tags: python, django

My app in django requires to tell the user what time an action occurred. Aside from asking the user what timezone he/she is in, is it possible for me to generate the time on the client end?

Off the top of my head, are there a particular representation of time that is timezone independent, (unix time?), and then I can simply paste it into the html and have the client end (browser) findout the timezone and then do the calculation?

Comment: I have consulted a few folks in #python and #jquery, timeago + epoch time is the best solution afaik

Answer (score 2):

I'd make all my times UTC, as that's a good international-level reference point, and you can always shift that to a local time, given that you know the user's TZ.

I'd also use the time on the *server* (`datetime.datetime.now()`) rather than rely on the client's system clock, as this makes it easy to fake what time something happened at.

Comment: `datetime.utcnow()` should be used on server.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used it myself, but I think [this](http://github.com/brosner/django-timezones) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are looking for [L10n](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/i18n/localization/) (localization) yes ???